# Migrating from PyQt3 to PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt

I am new on python and I would like to know how can I change a code written for PyQt3 to work on PyQt4. For example: the code bellow should work fine for PyQt3, what should I change on it to make it work on PyQt4?

Thanks.

```
import sys
from qt import *

class dlgLabel(QDialog):

def __init__(self,parent = None,name = None,modal = 0,fl = 0):
    QDialog.__init__(self,parent,name,modal,fl)
    self.setCaption("label dialog")
    if name == None:
        self.setName("dlgLabel")

    self.layout=QHBoxLayout(self)
    self.layout.setSpacing(6)
    self.layout.setMargin(11)

    self.label=QLabel("&Enter some text", self)
    self.edit=QLineEdit(self)
    self.label.setBuddy(self.edit)

    self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
    self.layout.addWidget(self.edit)

    self.edit.setFocus()

if __name__ == '__main__':
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
QObject.connect(app, SIGNAL('lastWindowClosed()'),
                app, SLOT('quit()'))
win = dlgLabel()
app.setMainWidget(win)
win.show()
app.exec_loop()
```

Comment: Are you tried to run this code with PyQt4?

Comment: Yes, I already tried. I know that I need to make some changes in the code to make it run properly, but since I am not expert I don't now what should I change.

Comment: Could you please add to your question, problems that you faced with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main differences will arise from differences between Qt 3 and Qt 4's APIs, which should be covered fairly well in http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/porting4-overview.html and several other Qt porting guides.

Checking out https://github.com/develersrl/pyqt3support might also be useful.

Comment: porting qt4 is not the same of porting pyqt4 , also pyqt3support , says that helps in porting but is  Qt's Qt3Support library , not migrate the code